# What's the difference between the two polar equations for ellipses?

Tags: conic-sections

$$ r(\theta) = \pm a \,  \frac{1-e^2}{1 \pm e \cos \theta} $$
What's the difference between the one with denominator $1+e \, \cos\theta$ and $1-e \, \cos\theta$ , and between +a and -a?

I see that most people use the one with $1+e \, \cos\theta$, which makes me confused.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you assume a range of $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ for $\theta$, the sign of the cosine does not actually matter (due to cosine being a symmetric function). But if you limit it to $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$, then you get the upper and lower halves with the different signs.

Comment: The answer is in the Wikipedia page about ellipses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse (with $+a$ instead of $-a$). With a minus sign in the denominator, it means that the reference direction $\theta = 0$ points towards the center of the ellipse (the origin is at a focus). It is strange to use $-a$ as it gives a negative polar radius.

Comment: Use $+a$ for an ellipse, $-a$ for a hyperbola. Use $\pm e\cos\theta$ to start from the nearest or farthest vertex at $\theta=0$ (for an ellipse) or to represent either branches of the curve (for a hyperbola).